# Single line command for logging IP

Tags: shell-script, logs, timestamps, ip-address

Is there a way to write something (in this case an external IP) with date & time and append it to a file? Is it possible to do it in one line?

I can do this:

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip >> ip.log
```

Which gives me this:

```
$ cat ip.log
X.X.X.X
```

However, I would like the log to read:

```
IP: X.X.X.X - 09/28/2017
IP: X.X.X.X - 09/29/2017
```

Comment: write a simple shell script to do it and call that from cron or whatever

Comment: Do you want the redirection/appending to happen on your command line (so that you can redirect it various places), or as part of the script/function/etc that does the rest of the work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf "IP: %s - %s\n" $(curl --silent ipinfo.io/ip) $(date +"%m/%d/%Y")
```

To have **Time** in the result, simply add `%T` shortened of `%H:%M:%S`.

```
printf "IP: %s - %s\n" $(curl --silent ipinfo.io/ip) $(date +"%m/%d/%Y-%T")
```

Just add this in crontab to get your desired output.

```
0 0 * * * printf "IP: %s - %s\n" $(curl -s ipinfo.io/ip) $(date +'\%m/\%d/\%Y') >>to-file
```

Comment: very slick, i like

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Added another part to include time. Ended up looking like this: printf "IP: %s - %s - %s\n" $(curl --silent ipinfo.io/ip) $(date +"[%T]") $(date +"%m/%d/%Y") >> ip.log

Comment: or `$(date +"%m/%d/%Y[%T]")` only : )